# failed to load resource after moving files offline

Tags: python, html

I'm serving HTML with a simple Python server with the following `do_GET` method:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import os
import mimetypes
import time

class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        print(self.path);
        if self.path == '/':
            self.path = '/v1.html'

            try:
                self.send_response(200)
                mimetype, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(self.path)
                self.send_header('Content-type', mimetype)
                self.end_headers()

                f = open(os.curdir + os.sep + self.path)
                self.wfile.write(bytes(f.read(), "UTF-8"))
                f.close()
            except IOError:
                self.send_error(404, 'file not found')
```

This was originally my HTML header:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Highchart</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", a href = "v1.css" />
    <script src='http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/spectrum.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/spectrum.css' />
    <script src='/external/customEvents.js'></script>
</head>
```

However all this is for an application that users should be able to use offline, so I had to copy all the external files and move them into a subdirectory /external, e.g.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Highchart</title>
    <script src="/external/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/external/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="/external/exporting.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href = "v1.css" />
    <script src='/external/spectrum.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/external/spectrum.css' />
    <script src='/external/customEvents.js'></script>
</head>
```

Since the change, frequently when running the server and opening localhost, one or more of the files hasn't loaded. When I switch back including the links to the online versions of the files, this doesn't happen at all and it gets progressively worse as I move more of the files offline.

I'm not experienced at all with servers and the like, so any guidance or hints as to what is the issue (and how I could resolve it) would be appreciated!